# How to display ckeditor saved html data from database to normal text in MVC 5

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I am using Mvc 5 razor,and have used ckeditor to save data in database but when i am retrieving data on the view it is coming with all the html tags pls helpme how to display it in normal text form on the view

```
     <div class="panel panel-default">
                        <a data-toggle="collapse" data-parent="#accordion" href="#collapseThree" id="Inclusions">
                            <div class="panel-heading">
                                <h4 class="panel-title">  INCLUSIONS </h4>
                            </div>
                        </a>
                        <div id="collapseThree" class="panel-collapse collapse">
                            <div class="panel-body">
                                @Html.Raw(Html.DisplayFor(Model => Model.Itinerarydetail.Inclusions));
                            </div>
                        </div>
                    </div>
```

Comment: You can use @Html.Raw for displaying raw html data, if that's what you are looking for. But I suggest you to edit your post and add your code, that you actually do to save and draw your field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use the `Html.DisplayFor` helper method, razor will encode the content before rendering. You should use `Html.Raw()` helper method which will not encode your content and pass the value you want to render directly to that.

```
<div class="panel-body">
    @Html.Raw(Model.Itinerarydetail.Inclusions)
</div>
```

Comment: Will this cause XSS vulnerability?

Comment: Here we are not showing the encoded version. So in that case, We should  encode it in the action method before sending to view.

Answer (score 1):

`Here in my view when you get data from database use @Html.Raw`

```
<div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Description,htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-sm-8">
            <textarea type="text" class="ckeditor" name="Description">@item.Description</textarea>
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Description, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
```